# multicol, ragged2e, RaggedLeft - How to "unjustify" last line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol, ragged2e

I try to use multicol with RaggedLeft from ragged2e. But Latex somehow "justifies" all lines including the last line of the paragraph. RaggedRight works as expected.

How can I achieve the look of RaggedRight but right-aligned?

EDIT: This is how it looks like for me (using xelatex):

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: This is how it looks using `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright`. Why should `RaggedLeft` in the left hand column produce hyphenation in the first line? Because it somehow "balances" the whole paragraph to have equal line widths. It doesn't happen with `\RaggedRight`

[image: Screenshot]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{black}}
\raggedcolumns

\usepackage{ragged2e}



\begin{document}

  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \RaggedLeft
    Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 100 Millionen haben.

    \columnbreak
    \RaggedRight
    Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference for me commenting out `\setmainfont{Arial}`. I've uploaded a picture.

Comment: Another name for `\RaggedLeft` is `FlushRight`, and that is what it does, it makes the right hand side of the text straight. Now there is a subtle difference with `\RaggedRight` or `FlushLeft`:  The end of the text is on the right hand side, and the default is to put the left-over space there. LaTeX can't do that with `\RaggedLeft`, because then the right hand side wouldn't be straight. It also cannot be put on the left hand side, because that would be in the middle of the text. That's the difference you see.

Comment: @gernot see the pictures in my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get the same breaks (with a short last line) if you add

```
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
```

But then you get

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{black}}
\raggedcolumns

\usepackage{ragged2e}



\begin{document}

  \begin{multicols}{2}
{    \RaggedLeft

\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil

    Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 100 Millionen haben.


\bigskip

    Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

}
    \columnbreak
{    \RaggedRight



    Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 100 Millionen haben.

\bigskip

    Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

}
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

so the easiest thing to do is not do that, and set it to 0pt, which is what `\raggedleft` and `\raggedLeft` do.

If you really want the short last line, you need to move the last line. In classic tex and xetex that really means working in a parbox as you can not manipulate the main vertical list, but in luatex there would be other possibilities.

---

One possibility with luatex

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{black}}
\raggedcolumns

\usepackage{ragged2e}



\begin{document}

  \begin{multicols}{2}
{    \RaggedRight
\pardir TRT

%\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil

    Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 100 Millionen haben.


\bigskip

    Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

}
    \columnbreak
{    \RaggedRight



    Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 100 Millionen haben.

\bigskip

    Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

}
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

---

and with xetex, in a `minipage`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{black}}
\raggedcolumns

\usepackage{ragged2e}



\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
{    \RaggedLeft
%\pardir TRT

\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil

    Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 100 Millionen haben.

\setbox0\lastbox
\nointerlineskip
\hbox to \linewidth{\hfill\unhbox0}


\bigskip

    Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

\setbox0\lastbox
\nointerlineskip
\hbox to \linewidth{\hfill\unhbox0}

}
    \columnbreak
{    \RaggedRight



    Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 100 Millionen haben.

\bigskip

    Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

}
  \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you also explain how the parbox solution for xetex works? Thank you!

Comment: @Chris done....

Answer (score 4):

What you see is the consequence of the asymmetry introduced by `ragged2e`, that allows hyphenation in order to fill up lines as much as possible.

Here's a comparison, first with `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright`, then with `\RaggedLeft` and `\RaggedRight`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{black}}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{document}

\section{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}raggedleft} and \texttt{\symbol{`\\}raggedright}}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedleft
Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres 
überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 
2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

\columnbreak

\raggedright
Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres 
überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 
2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedleft
Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. 
ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 
in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 
100 Millionen haben.

\columnbreak

\raggedright
Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. 
ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 
in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 
100 Millionen haben.

\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedleft
Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. 
ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 
in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 
100 Millionen haben.

\columnbreak

\raggedright
Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres 
überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 
2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

\end{multicols}

\section{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}RaggedLeft} and \texttt{\symbol{`\\}RaggedRight}}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\RaggedLeft
Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres 
überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 
2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

\columnbreak

\RaggedRight
Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres 
überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 
2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\RaggedLeft
Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. 
ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 
in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 
100 Millionen haben.

\columnbreak

\RaggedRight
Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. 
ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 
in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 
100 Millionen haben.

\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\RaggedLeft
Die langwierigen Verhandlungen sind damit gescheitert. 
ARD und ZDF sollen für die Sublizenzen der Winterspiele 2018 
in Pyeongchang und der Sommerspiele 2020 in Tokio maximal 
100 Millionen haben.

\columnbreak

\RaggedRight
Discovery hatte sich im Sommer des vergangenen Jahres 
überraschend die Rechte für den europäischen Markt von 
2018 bis 2024 gesichert.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]